# Remove rows from LinkedList

Tags: list, linked-list, anylogic

In my anylogic model, I want to add orderID, processing time and due date to a list on enter of a queue block. This works fine. Now I would like to remove this information from the list at the moment that the order leaves the queue, so on exit, but I can't get it to work.

I have the following:

```java
class ExportInfo {
    private int id;
    private int P;
    private double d;

    public ExportInfo(int id, int P, double d) { 
           this.id=id;
           this.P=P;
           this.d=d;
    }
}

LinkedList<ExportInfo> list = new LinkedList();
```

At my queue block on enter:

```java
new ExportInfo(agent.atrID, agent.atrEstimatedPackingTime, dateToTime(agent.atrDueDate));

list.add(new ExportInfo(agent.atrID, agent.atrEstimatedPackingTime, dateToTime(agent.atrDueDate)));
```

On exit:

```java
new ExportInfo(agent.atrID, agent.atrEstimatedPackingTime, dateToTime(agent.atrDueDate));
list.remove(new ExportInfo(agent.atrID, agent.atrEstimatedPackingTime, dateToTime(agent.atrDueDate)));
```

At some point, I write the results to an Excel file. I first checked the results if I only add the info to the list. In the Excel file I see all the info of the orders that came in (let's say there where 6).

Then I also tried with `remove`, which would mean that at the moment the info is written to Excel, it should only contain info from orders that have not left the queue (since in that case their info should have been removed from the list). I can see that there are 4 orders in the queue at the moment i write info to my Excel file, however still the information of all the 6 orders that entered the queue is there, so the info of the 2 orders that have left the queue has not been removed.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are constantly adding and removing new instances of `ExportInfo`, this does not make sense.

Add entries once in the queue block on enter. Also, store the `ExportInfo` inside the actual agent as a variable `myExportInfo` so it remembers it until the queue exit.

In the Queue exit, you want to *change* the exit time in your `ExportInfo` object, but not create a new one. So use a setter for the queue exit time, like `agent.myExportInfo.setExitTime(...)`

This will give you a full list of all agents that passed through the queue

Comment: Yes, I am probably not working the most efficient way, I am just starting to learn java coding and anylogic. In short, what I want is: After one hour (that is when the event happens), have the information of only the orders that are still in the queue in Excel.  And after another hour, have the information in excel of the orders that are in the queue at that moment, etc. etc. This info may also be saved in a new sheet. Do you know how I could make sure I get the right info in excel?

Answer (score 0):

`remove` will not find the object, because you constructed a *new* object which by consequence is not in the list yet.

You should either:

1. Retain a reference to the object that you created at the time you *added* it to the list, and use that reference when calling `remove`.
2. (Less efficient:) Iterate the list and look for an object that has the properties you are looking for, and then remove it.

Comment: Could you give an example of how it would look like to retain e reference to an object at the time it is added to the list? I am not sure what you mean by that. I have tried list.remove(agent.atrID) and the same for packing time and due date, but it gives the error 'Exception during discrete event execution:
Index: 6, Size: 6
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6'

Comment: So you would do `ExportInfo myRef = new ExportInfo( .......); list.add(myRef);` and then later on you would just do `list.remove(myRef)`. The challenge will be to do this for multiple entries, so you may need a mapping (HashMap) to map a key to a `ExportInfo` object.

Comment: With a hashmap you would do `map.put(agent.atrID, myRef)` right after you created `myRef`, and at the moment of removal: `list.remove(map.get(agent.atrID))`... etc. And if you don't use the list for anything else, you might just drop the list, and only work with the hashmap.